# Azure Active Directory Implicit flow- Restrict users who can log in

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I have implemented the aad implicit flow for web app. I want to restrict users who can log in to the web app. I created a user group and added that in Users and Groups option. I enabled the user assignment required option. The problem is when I enable the option Azure AD login screen asks me for Admin Consent. None of the scopes requires Admin Consent.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1RYu.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's not the cause of the user assignment required option, it is the required by the implicit flow. I tried on my side, when the user assignment required option is disabled and the scopes don't require admin consent, the user is still required admin consent.

[image]